# circleci (v2.0) using npm when yarn is the run command

Tags: reactjs, circleci, yarnpkg

There's documentation on setting up yarn for circleci v1 but not v2 because it appears as though they've got yarn baked into the v2 api, however, in my config.yml i explicitly run yarn to install my deps yet, when i review the build logs it shows that npm is used for all my yarn commands... I obviously need to override this / install yarn? Unfortunately it appears that the v2 docs don't touch on this and my google-foo isn't being fruitful...

what's more interesting is that another one of my projects IS using yarn with almost the exact same config... what gives?

heres my current config.yml

```
# Javascript Node CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
#
# Check https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-javascript/ for more details
#
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      - image: circleci/node:7.10

      # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
      # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
      # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
      # - image: circleci/mongo:3.4.4

    working_directory: ~/repo

    steps:
      - checkout

      # Download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
          # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
          - v1-dependencies-

      - run: yarn

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - node_modules
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}

      # run tests!
      - run: yarn test
      - run: echo "ALL GOOD IN THE HOOD"
      - deploy:
          name: Deploy on deploy branch
          command: |
            if [ "${CIRCLE_BRANCH}" == "deploy" ]; then
              ./node_modules/.bin/firebase ...
            fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. My circleci folder was misspelled. I omitted the `.` and it was using a default config... sigh...